# Designing an HTML/javascript control that allows for customizable styling

Tags: javascript, html

A short way of asking this question is, "how should be I go about designing html+js controls that are reusable?"

I like writing ui controls in html and javascript for inclusion on a web page.  (Think: widgets, photo pickers, stock tickers, calendar, etc..).

I can write my javascript with a decent architecture (oo design, model-view-presenter, etc..).  I have javascript code and css in seperate files.  The html markup hosting the control merely has to reference the script and stylesheet files then initialize an instance of my control with the parent DOM element during the onload event.

What I struggle with is a good pattern of having my own control be reusable elsewhere, while allowing for customizable styling without having to fork the CSS file every time.

There are certain style attributes that are meant to be tweaked for each use (color, font, size, etc.).  But there are style attributes for the control's internal children that aren't meant to be changed. (e.g. position: absolute, border-collase, overflow).  And it get wonky when there are certain internal children that need to be sized with respect to the overall size of the control.

What strategies could I use to make re-use easy for the guy who wants to re-use my widget without having to fork the code or CSS files that were originally written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its name suggests CSS applies on cascade, so you can define a master CSS file with core styles (not meant to be changed) and default values for styles that are succeptible to be changed, and then a kind of template for these values that the user can use to define custom styles.

Think of the master CSS as something like:

```
.widget-frame {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000000;
    ...
}

.widget-frame h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    color: 1E1E1E;
    ...
}
...
```

and then the custom CSS file that could look like:

```
.widget-frame {
    /*Body of the widget*/
}

.widget-frame h1 {
    /*Title of the widget*/
}
...
```

so the user to change the colors only should have to take this custom CSS file and add for example `color`, `background`, etc... properties to the different elements that will overwrite the master CSS properties (remember to load the custom CSS file **after** the master to overwrite)

It's an additional file to load so in case you need extreme performance maybe is not the best aproach, but in most cases the overhead is minimum and this allows to customize easily the components without having to worry to fork the master CSS file and dig in the elements/properties to see what you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

separate the layout and the style of the css, so that any customisable properties (color, border, font-family, etc) are all in one css file together.

i would also pick a common pre-fix for all your class names - i.e. .my-widget-wrapper, .my-widget-header, etc. don't force people to write selectors like this:

```
div.my-widget-wrapper div h1 span span.close a
```

when they could just do

```
a.my-widget-close-button
```